# Reverse with " " no argument Not Found. Django (NoReverseMatchError

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, bootstrap-modal

I am a beginner in django. I have a problem with class based delete view as its returning a no reverse match error. A dollar symbol is there at the end of the url which I didn't provide.

This is the error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /posts/myhome/
Reverse for 'delete_post' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/delete$']
```

views.py

```
class DeletePostView(BSModalDeleteView, LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin):
model = Post
success_url = reverse_lazy('posts:myhome')
template_name = 'posts/delete_post.html'

def test_func(self):
    post = self.get_object()
    if self.request.user == post.user:
        return True
    return False
```

html code:

```
 <div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="modal-body">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4" style="text-align: center;">Delete Post</legend>
            <h4 style="text-align: center;">Are you sure you want to delete this post?</h4>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center;">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger" type="submit">Yes, Delete</button>
           %}">Cancel</a> -->
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('myhome/', HomePostListView.as_view(), name='myhome'),
path('create/', CreatePostView.as_view(), name='create_post'),
path('<slug>/', views.detail_post, name='detail_post'),
path('<slug>/update', views.update_post, name='update_post'),
path('<slug>/delete', DeletePostView.as_view(), name='delete_post'),]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't because of these codes or not because of the kwargs. There was a problem with the javascript in myhome.html which I changed and everything was back to normal.

and thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd like to welcome you to SO! I too am new to this platform, so I understand where you're coming from. I'd like to call attention to your formatting of the HTML code, namely the `%}">Cancel</a> -->"`you have right below the submit button. I don't think that's the issue here but it's something that might have been erroneously copy pasted.

Secondly, it'd be super helpful to understand django's url pattern regex:[Django Url Regex Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQSe3.jpg)
Image Source: https://www.webforefront.com/django/regexpdjangourls.html

This is helpful to explain why the error output shows the dollar sign at the end of that attempted reverse, since it marks the end of line for the regex pattern, which reverse_lazy uses.

The crux of your issue seems to stem from the fact that you are not passing in an argument to the delete_post view, as it requires a slug.

The [Django 2.2 Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) for the reverse function state:
If the URL accepts arguments, you may pass them in args. For example:

```
from django.urls import reverse

def myview(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('arch-summary', args=[1945]))
```

You can also pass kwargs instead of args. For example:

```
>>> reverse('admin:app_list', kwargs={'app_label': 'auth'})
'/admin/auth/'
```

You need to pass the slug of the post you're attempting to delete to that reverse function.

Comment: I am not able to resolve it with kwargs. still showing the same error. Infact I can open the url specifically in the browser without the error.